# php from string to echo

Tags: php

I have a "big" string like `something here blah bla <b>tomato</b> something else kasjd ajsd`

From this I am trying to extract `tomato`.

What is the function to use to do this based on getting the position in the big string of the strings to the left and right of the target string?

so like I have:

```
start: "bla <b>"
end: "</b> some"
```

and I want what is between them in the big string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

echo get_string_between(
     'something here blah bla <b>tomato</b> something else kasjd ajsd',
      'bla <b>',
      '</b> some'
);
```

[**See it working here**](http://codepad.org/CKznF00L) on codepad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$things = split("<[/]?b>", $string);
```

This will return an array of anything inbetween **xxx** i.e if there are multiple 's in your string will give you them.

Answer (score 0):

@David19801: If the "keyword" you're trying to extract will always be the same and is known, why not

```
$pieces = explode("tomato", $bigstring);
$left   = $pieces[0];
$right  = $pieces[1];
```

Comment: Sometimes it is a number that can change frequently.  I just know what is to its right and left...